# How to align views evenly and nicely ordered

Tags: android

I always face this problem and I feel that I design it bad.

if I want to display an activity (settings type of activity) where my user can input a name, choose an item, and check a toggle item. As follows  I would like to align the EditText, spinner and button under neath each other in which they occupy the right half of the screen and the text occupies the left side.
Do I use

- Nested linear layouts with weights (which I never seem to get it right)
- Relative Layout where I align things and  I use center in parent property to get it starting from half screen (too many IDs are defined in XML file even for lables that I won't use in the code)
- Table layout

Which one you recommend? or maybe how?

[image]

Comment: Do ids defined in XML layout file impact the app in any negative way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For perfect alignment I think the TableLayout is the best option in your case. You can do this using other two options. But if the text length of the left side changes then you may need to change the xml layouts. But by using tableLayout that will be more easy to manage.

Comment: A sample will be appreciated but I like your direct answer

Answer (score 1):

From the image you provided above, it seems you have TextDetails on left side and View on right such that right view must start from centerVertical. Is it right??

I suggest you use `TableLayout`... Add your views as you mentioned above..

You can set width hardcoded so that they remain intact always like this..

```
float screenWidth = ((Activity) context).getWindowManager()
                    .getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
```

then your views both TextDetails and View's add `setWidth(screenWidth / 2);`

Comment: Good idea +1 but I was hoping for more of xml solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to go throw Android [desing patters](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/index.html). There are some tips about how to do this better. On my opinion - just use LinearLayout and manipulate with their gravity/margin/padding. Or use RelativeLayout instead like google recommends.

Best wishes.

Comment: Thank you but is there an explanation.